# Allow ray to see through properties?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

Here is my code:

```
import bge
from bge import logic

controllor = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

target = scene.objects['Target']
ray = controllor.sensors['Ray']

if (ray.hitObject and not 'Fire_False' in ray.hitObject):
    target.worldPosition = ray.hitPosition
```

I've noticed that if you have an object with the prop "Fire_False" and **an object *behind* it *without* the prop, the ray *doesn't* track to the object behind the first**. I am looking to modify this script so the ray can look through the object with the prop and find other objects *behind it*. If the script sees a situation like this, it uses the object with the prop as a **dead end**, and does *not* continue tracking. How can I have this ray see though props? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: I would also like this to work *if an object in in another object* and the bound object does have Fire_False, but the object in it **doesn't**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of this backwards from how the ray sensor works. You want to look for "target" no mater what is in front of it.

Add a property to everything you want to get hit say *"target"*. Then change the ray senor to look only for that property (*"target"*) and enable *X-Ray Mode*.
[image: Ray sensor]

Last your code can then look like this.

```
if ray.hitObject:
    target.worldPosition = ray.hitPosition
```

*X-Ray Mode* will let the ray look through everything, and the property will only return the objects with the property "target."

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear on this. I need the ray to detect objects *without* the property *Fire_False*. The ray and script is in the camera. An empty is named "target" and *that empty tracks to where the ray stops*. When I use x-ray, **the ray uses the *last used* position**.

Comment: @blackhole I understood that from your question. You are still going to have to change the ray sensor look for a property (call it whatever you want I used "target") on all objects that you *want* to get hit. There is no way to use X-Ray Mode and script it to look only for objects that do not have "Fire_False."

Comment: @blackhole i'm assuming you're using this so you can't shoot your allies and stuff. What david is saying is correct, you want to put a property on all of the badguys that means that you can shoot. or you may have the guns default always shoot and the allies in the crosshairs means you can't. it depends on the situation.

Comment: @Radish of the Opera You can shoot the good guys, that is not a part of this. I need an empty that is always at the center of the screen *that collides with objects without the prop Fire_False*. The objects *with* Fire_False are objects that trigger events and are invisible, or are **not a part of the game**. I already have *tons* of work put into this after I figured out what to do, and changing everything would be difficult. I am just looking for an x-ray to work.