# X-ray mode problem

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

For a ray sensor, I want it to detect object **without** a specified prop. I will put it as invert. If I use invert with x-ray mode, it will invert *the* x-ray mode. How can I use x-ray mode to detect an object without a prop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by a logic operation and two ray sensors :

1- the first ray sensor detects objects with **prop**  
 
2- the second ray sensor detects any objects

the objects you  want to detect are any object except the ones that have **prop** so use the expression :  `Ray_2 and Not Ray_1`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, never thought of this this way. I have another issue: I have the ray > python. You have an expression. For this scenario, I'm assuming I put the expression in the script. How would I do this? (**I have it where an object will track to the ray.hitObject, *the reason I need python***) My code is in this problem: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32729/allow-ray-to-see-through-properties

Comment: Would this new issue be another question or would you like another answer to your current problem?

Comment: @blackhole you should have specified that either in the the question or its tags,BTW you already have the right code :   **if (ray.hitObject and not 'prop' in ray.hitObject):**

Comment: Well, I also thought that was the right code. The problem is, if an object is inside/behind an object with the prop, the ray will *not* track to it. Thus, I needed x-ray mode but I was using invert, so I had to think of something. I thought of this [question] in hopes of it solving it. Anyways, the code is good but I need x-ray. If I toggle it, it won't work as I have it as invert.

Comment: @blackhole X-Ray depends on the prop to decide if it should pass through or stop at this object , i think the easy way would be to add a prop2 to all other objects that don't have prop and set the ray-sensor to look for prop2 in X-Ray mode

Comment: I, at first, didn't want to do that as I would have to put a prop on every game object. After some time, I decided to. For some reason, it cannot detect enemies **that have to prop**. I looked all over it, and I have no idea why.